# Find a critical function

Tags: functional-analysis, euler-lagrange-equation

The functional is:

$$L=\int{u\sqrt{1+(u')^2}}dx$$

when:
$$u'(0)=0, u(1)=2 $$

the steps that I did:
$$ F=u\sqrt{1+(u')^2} $$
$$ F_u=\sqrt{1+(u')^2} $$
$$ F_{u'}=\frac{uu'}{\sqrt{1+(u')^2}} $$

because $$F_x =0$$ I can use Beltrami identity instead of EL
$$F-u'F_{u'}=c$$

$$u\sqrt{1+(u')^2}-u'\frac{uu'}{\sqrt{1+(u')^2}}=c$$

$$\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+(u')^2}}=c$$

$$\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+(u')^2}}=c$$

$$\frac{u^2}{c^2}=1+(u')^2$$

$$u'=\pm\frac{\sqrt{u^2-c^2}}{c^2}$$

$$\frac{du}{dx}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{u^2-c^2}}{c}$$

$$dx=\pm c\frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-c^2}}$$

$$x=\pm c\int{\frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-c^2}}}=\pm c \ln{|u+\sqrt{u^2-c^2}|}$$

in this step I can use $u(1)=2$ to find $c$, but I'm still not sure how to  find the critical function.

but I feel that something wrong with this solution, any help welcome

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

You need two integration constants.

$$
\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u'^2}} = C_1
$$

and after

$$
dx = \pm \frac{C_1 du}{\sqrt{u^2-C_1^2}}
$$

giving

$$
x = C_2 \pm C_1\ln\left|u+\sqrt{u^2-C_1^2}\right|
$$

After inversion

$$
\cases{
u = \frac 12 e^{-\frac{C_2+x}{C_1}}\left(C_1^2 e^{\frac{2C_2}{C_1}}+e^{\frac{2x}{C_1}}\right)\\
u = \cdots
}
$$

and finally determine $C_1, C_2$ according to the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you! but bay their is more elegant way to sold it?

Comment: $u$ can be expressed also as $$ u = \frac 12\left((1-C_1^2)\sinh(\frac{C_2-x}{C_1})+(1+C_1^2)\cosh(\frac{C_2-x}{C_1})\right)$$

Comment: How did you come up with this solution?